# Breadcrumbs arrow rtl direction

Tags: html, css

I modified the code Breadcrumbs arrow for working in right to left direction but text not working fine this code in jsfiddle look how text show : jsfiddle.net/tr7th3d2

```
<style>

    .breadcrumb { 
        list-style: none; 
        overflow: hidden; 
        font: 18px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    }
    .breadcrumb li { 
        float: left; 
    }
    .breadcrumb li a {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none; 
        padding: 10px 0 10px 55px;
        background: brown;                   /* fallback color */
        background: hsla(34,85%,35%,1); 
        position: relative; 
        display: block;
        float: left;
    }
    .breadcrumb li a:after { 
        content: " "; 
        display: block; 
        width: 0; 
        height: 0;
        border-top: 50px solid transparent;           /* Go big on the size, and let overflow hide */
        border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
        border-right: 30px solid hsla(34,85%,35%,1);
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -50px; 
        right: 100%;
        z-index: 2; 
    }   
    .breadcrumb li a:before { 
        content: " "; 
        display: block; 
        width: 0; 
        height: 0;
        border-top: 50px solid transparent;           /* Go big on the size, and let overflow hide */
        border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
        border-right: 30px solid white;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -50px; 
        margin-right: 1px;
        right: 100%;
        z-index: 1; 
    }   
    .breadcrumb li:first-child a {
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,45%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a:after { border-right-color: hsla(34,85%,45%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,55%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) a:after { border-right-color: hsla(34,85%,55%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(4) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,65%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(4) a:after { border-right-color: hsla(34,85%,65%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(5) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,75%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(5) a:after { border-right-color: hsla(34,85%,75%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li a:hover { background: hsla(34,85%,25%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li a:hover:after { border-right-color: hsla(34,85%,25%,1) !important; }

</style>


<div id="page-wrap">


    <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Vehicles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Vans</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Camper Vans</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">1989 VW Westfalia Vanagon</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

and this original code :
https://css-tricks.com/triangle-breadcrumbs/

Answer (score 0):

you must change a tag padding

```
  .breadcrumb li a { 
    padding: 10px 55px 10px 0px;
}
```